# Set permissions on a specific user for /var/www

Tags: permissions, apache2, 22.04, chmod

I have a standard user on an Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop VM named "user1". The VM is running apache2.

I would like user1 to not be able to access the contents of the folder /var/wwww to keep the contents secure. A visitor to the webpage should still be able to access the site as expected.

My attempted solution was

```
sudo chmod 770 /var/www
```

thinking that this would prevent user1 from accessing the contents. Well, that worked, but now visiting the webpage produces a "forbidden" error from Apache. Makes sense.

What is the proper way to set these permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set at least the group for user `www-data`, which is the group of the user of the apache process.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R o-rwx,g+rX /var/www
```

If already working as root, `sudo` is not needed (thanks for the comment)

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. For those following along, make sure you type "sudo" before these commands if you are not root.